# The google always notice that some app can damage your device

Tags: android

we develop an App named "tracksolid".

[image]

it had entered some Application market include google market.but when the users download our Application and installed on their Android phone,the google play always nocice that our app can damage their device?our App is safe and service for many business people,this notice gives us a bad influence.

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This popup is shown when the app is using any dangerous permissions.

Check more details in developer docs on permissions

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/declaring.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html